# Windows Server 2003 stopped to recognize exe files

Tags: windows-server-2003

When I try to launch a exe file, I get the following error message:

> Windows cannot open this file

Also, Windows Explorer is unable to recognize the file type for any kind of file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it's f--ked.

(Slightly) long(er) answer: sounds like something as described [here](http://filext.com/faq/broken_exe_association.php) is happening.  Try the fix described on that link: it's for XP but should also work on 2003.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like the Swen virus.  If that is the case, go here:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/fixvirii/#download and download the VBS script that will change the defaults back.

NOTE:  I can't guarantee whether or not this will help so don't blindly run the script.  Be sure and have a backup of the server first.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you do happen to find a virus, it's really time for a wipe/reinstall. Never trust a system that has been infected, especially a server. Back up that thing and start fresh.